# What does the "Programs" header line in gcov mean

Tags: c, gcc, gcov

I am used to seeing these header lines in GCOV files when I run a unit test executable once:

```
        -:    0:Source:../../src/file1.c
        -:    0:Graph:build/file1.gcno
        -:    0:Data:build/file1.gcda
        -:    0:Runs:1
        -:    0:Programs:1
```

However, sometimes I see headers that look like this:

```
        -:    0:Source:../../src/file2.c
        -:    0:Programs:2
```

I am not sure why the headers look different. Both test directories/makefiles are setup the same way. The coverage data also looks totally correct for file2.

Specifically why is "Programs:2"? What does this line mean? I've looked at the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcov.1.html) but can't find any explanation for what that heading means. Intuitively, I'd think that it means that the associated object was linked into an executable twice instead of once. But that isn't the case, there is only one executable and it is only run once.

Edit: I am using gcov 7.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for gcov 7.5.0 is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/releases/gcc-7.5.0/gcc/gcov.c).

The snippet below shows where headers are printed. File2 happens to be in a directory with multiple source files. Because of that the graph, data, and runs headers are being omitted.

```
File: gcov.c
2506:   fprintf (gcov_file, "%9s:%5d:Source:%s\n", "-", 0, src->coverage.name);
2507:   if (!multiple_files)
2508:     {
2509:       fprintf (gcov_file, "%9s:%5d:Graph:%s\n", "-", 0, bbg_file_name);
2510:       fprintf (gcov_file, "%9s:%5d:Data:%s\n", "-", 0,
2511:          no_data_file ? "-" : da_file_name);
2512:       fprintf (gcov_file, "%9s:%5d:Runs:%u\n", "-", 0, object_runs);
2513:     }
2514:   fprintf (gcov_file, "%9s:%5d:Programs:%u\n", "-", 0, program_count);
2515:
```

`program_count` is incremented at line 1570. I'm assuming this happens twice because there are two data files.